# How to set attribute for checkbox field

Tags: theming, forms

I want to add the attribute `data-toggle="toggle"` to a checkbox field.

I thought I could use the hook theme_checkbox which is:

```
function theme_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  $element ['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element ['#checked'])) {
    $element ['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element ['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

So I customised it to:

```
function mytheme_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  $element ['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element ['#checked'])) {
    $element ['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }

  //*******Added 3 lines below*******
  if ($element['#attributes']['id'] = 'edit-profile-carer-field-profile-active-und') {
      element_set_attributes($element, array('#attributes' => 'data-toggle="toggle"'));
  }

  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element ['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

However, instead of just adding the attribute `data-toggle="toggle"` to the checkbox field  with the id *edit-profile-carer-field-profile-active-und*, it is adding the attribute to all the checkboxes on the form.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I target just the the checkbox I want? Or do I need to use another approach to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you do this via a form alter.  But that aside, the reason your code doesn't work is that you're not doing your comparison correctly.

```
if ($element['#attributes']['id'] = 'edit-profile-carer-field-profile-active-und') {
```

Should be:

```
if ($element['#attributes']['id'] == 'edit-profile-carer-field-profile-active-und') {
```

And you're also not setting the attribute correctly.  So the final function should be:

```
function mytheme_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  $element ['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element ['#checked'])) {
    $element ['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }

  //*******Added 3 lines below*******
  if ($element['#attributes']['id'] == 'edit-profile-carer-field-profile-active-und') {
      $element['#attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'toggle';
  }

  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element ['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Aaron for your help. It is all working now. I did initially try hook_form_alter, but that added the attribute to the field containing div rather than the actual input element.

Comment: You could have done it with a form alter but would have had to identify the right element in the massive array tree. Anyhow...if my answer helped, @Ben, please click the check mark next to my answer to accept it.

Comment: I clicked the check mark next to your answer when I added my previous comment. It is now showing green for me. Is it not showing as checked for you? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  Weird, wasn't showing earlier.  Caching...? Thanks!